# Is there an pysimplegui function to get the the loction of the input cursor?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am making an application which includes a form, at some point, I have a multiline element that must be filled by the user and I need the cursor location because the user must indicate after a specific text location of the multiline element.

I have try to access to the Tkinter method : `print(t.index(tk.INSERT))` , but I got stuck.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see any method to do this. Framework may not have this function to make it simply. And it may use `PyQt` instead of `tkinter` so it may have only functions avaliable in both frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `t` is your PySimpleGUI element, `t.Widget` should give you access to the underlying Tkinter widget.

```
print(t.Widget.index(tk.INSERT))
```